# hibernate session refresh not working

Tags: hibernate

Wanted to understand how refresh works ? below mentioned is code.

```
Session session = factory.openSession();
session.beginTransaction();
Article a = (Article)session.load(Article.class,4L);
System.out.println(a.getArtDesc());
Thread.sleep(10000);
session.refresh(a);
System.out.println(a.getArtDesc());
session.getTransaction().commit();
session.close();
```

during 10 seconds sleep have changed the article description from back-end but still after refresh function updated article description is not coming ? Any Help is Appreciated.

Comment: What isolation level are you using?

Comment: have not defined any isolation level. believe default will be committed_read in that case committed transaction from mysql tool should get reflected.